# Shell script run in web browser shows empty results

Tags: shell, web, browser, asterisk

I've written a shell script in CentOS. It basically connects to a database and displays certain information.
i have put at the beginning the following instructions:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""
```

If I run it in the Linux Command line I get the results and the output as desired, but If I run it using the web browser, it displays nothing. I have put the script in the cgi-bin directory. As additional information I have some other scripts using nmap and curl working without problem.

Basically I want to display the status of some extensions in Asterisk IP-PBX

```
for i in `asterisk -rx 'sip show peers'|grep -ai Uns |sort -n |grep ^2| awk '{print $1}' | grep [a-z]`; do
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You have put full path to asterisk.

Also you have test script under same user as your webserver. Very likly you have change in /etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf permissions for asterisk ctl file.